# find last html element with jquery for special attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table. Always multiple row in the table contain a attribute like `selectrow="selectrow"`. For example 3rd and 4th row have `selectrow="selectrow"` attribute. Now i want to find out the index of last row that have  `selectrow="selectrow"` attribute. I do not want to use each. I search for solution like this :

```
$("table > tbody > tr[selectrow='selectrow']:last-child").index();
```

This is html:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr >
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr selectrow="selectrow">
  </tr>
  <tr selectrow="selectrow">
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example i want to get 4.

Comment: so what's the problem with `$("table > tbody > tr[selectrow='selectrow']:last-child").index();` ?

Comment: that return the index of last row in the table.in the other word that ignore the attribute.

Comment: I would have thought it returned `-1` as no elements with that attribute is also the last child of the parent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : use `:last` which will give you last of the matched selection. `:last-child` will select the last child of table and try to match the other selection criteria (`selectrow='selectrow'` in your case) and when match not found then it will retrun -1.

```
$("table > tbody > tr[selectrow='selectrow']:last").index();
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjaLsnLh/6/)**

More Information on 
**[:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)**
**[:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("table > tbody > tr[selectrow='selectrow']").last();
```

it will return the object of last `tr`.